# Max storage space for trace logs SharePoint On Premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, uls, diagnostics

In the diagnostic logging section of the SP CA settings, you have an option to choose the maximum storage space of the trace logs. So, I was wondering if that storage space is a summary for all SP servers or its space for each server individually. I was trying to find a good explanation for it, but I was not able to, if you have such a documentation where that is explained, can you please share it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn’t find any document for this statement, but here’s what I found from testing:

1. The setting for Maximum storage space for Trace Logs is **farm** scoped. 
   Also when we change this setting using `Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -LogDiskSpaceUsageGB 500`, it changes the value on the farm.
2. The number of Maximum storage space for Trace Logs is **server** specific, not a summary for all SP servers.

   This is the result for two servers when I set the number to 8:

   [image]

References:
[Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-diagnostic-logging#configure-diagnostic-logging-by-using-central-administration)

Comment: Thanks a lot Chelsea, I have just got results from my tests too and they are saying the same, it looks like an individual size for each server, not a summary.